# CarrierWave Json Column with meta information

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, image-processing, carrierwave

I'm working on an image upload feature and would like to take advantage of the new JSON column for storing multiple uploads on a post.  This would be in place of the separate table approach in which each row stores all the image information (including the url for it, the post id it belongs to, etc).  This new feature in Carrierwave is documented here: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads

The issue is it seems by default CarrierWave simply stores the string url representation of the image.  I would like store additional information though, like image description, title, keywords, dimensions, etc.  JSON in theory is perfect for this type of thing.  Has anyone tried doing this and how would one go about it?